# Why site info not shown in social applications

Tags: asp.net, web, meta-tags, telegram

I'm developing a website, I want to show my site info in social application like telegram when my site link is set. like the image below.
[image]

I set these tag on head site:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="desc" />
```

but nothing happen!
What should I do?

Comment: you are using open graph tags, which some websites like facebook and linkedin use, but not all of them, you also have no `og:image` property, no twitter or pinterest tags etc, which particular social networks are you targetting?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i set all of them

Comment: which social networks is this reproducable on,  and have you used the facebook opengraph debugger to check the tags and to re-fetch the contents?

Comment: <meta name="description" content="sample desc" />
<meta name="author" content="author " />
<meta name="image" content="Images/logo.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="logo.png" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="sample desc">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="sample title">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="logo.png">

Comment: I want when I send my site link, to application like telegram messenger, my site info shown as the image above, 
no, I don't use face book debugger,

Comment: the open grapph debugger from facebook is the only one I know of, use it to check your page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ This is an example of the settings to use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.rottentomatoes.com%2Fm%2Fmatrix%2F - make sure you include the full path to your image starting with `htttp://`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I test my link, face book debugger can not scrape it

Comment: this line should not have a `;` and needs the `http://` - try ` <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />`  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />` - if this still does not work in the facebook debugger then use a HTML validator to check the code, eg http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks @Mousey , I tell the result

Answer (score 0):

I found that my site can not be seen from outside of my country!
and that is the problem!

Comment: that is very strange!